# problem in creating binary search tree in c language

Tags: c, malloc, binary-search-tree, undefined-behavior, sizeof

This code creates a binary search tree but it
runs sometimes normally and sometimes makes errors, even without changing anything in the code.

I can't get why this happening, what's the mistake ?

Even I changed the function that I used to create the tree from recursive to iterative but the same results.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sommet{
    struct sommet * fg;
    int val;
    struct sommet * fd;
}sommet;
typedef sommet* ptrm;

ptrm creearbre(ptrm arbre,int ele);
void impression(ptrm arbre);
ptrm creearbre_rec(ptrm arbre,int ele);

int main()
{
        ptrm arbre=NULL;
        int tarbre,n;
        printf("entre la taille de l'arbre:");
        scanf("%d",&tarbre);
        for(int i=0;i<tarbre;i++)
        {
            printf("entre l'element %d: ",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&n);
            arbre=creearbre_rec(arbre,n);
        }
        impression(arbre);
    return 0;
}

ptrm creearbre_rec(ptrm arbre,int ele)
{
    if(arbre==NULL)
    {
        arbre=malloc(sizeof arbre);
        arbre->val=ele;
        arbre->fd=NULL;
        arbre->fg=NULL;
    }
    else if(arbre->val > ele)
        arbre->fg=creearbre_rec(arbre->fg,ele);
    else
        arbre->fd=creearbre_rec(arbre->fd,ele);
return arbre;
}

void impression(ptrm arbre){
        if(arbre != NULL){
        printf(" %d -->", arbre->val);
        impression(arbre->fg);
        impression(arbre->fd);
    }
}


ptrm creearbre(ptrm arbre,int ele){
    ptrm p,q=arbre,r=NULL;
    p=malloc(sizeof arbre);
    p->val=ele;
    p->fd=NULL;
    p->fg=NULL;
    if(arbre==NULL){
        arbre=p;
    }
    else{
        while(q!=NULL){
            r=q;
            if(ele > q->val)
                q=q->fd;
            else
                q=q->fg;
        }
        if(ele > r->val)
            r->fd=p;
        else
            r->fg=p;
    }
    return arbre;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "*makes errors*" is not a very useful description. Please give the exact errors. Usually by providing the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Don't typedef pointers. It just makes it confusing for yourself and others. It could be one reason why you do things like this which are wrong: `malloc(sizeof arbre);`. That should be `malloc(sizeof *arbre);`

Comment: Second that. do NOT hide pointer types in aliases. It proffers absolutely zero clarity to the code when used incorrectly (e.g *all* cases but two: "handle"-based blackbox APIs, and callback function types, *neither* of which are applicable to you). C programmers want to "see the splats". They're the visual calling card that proclaim "this is a pointer". Don't fight that; embrace it.

Comment: Please [edit] and add an example of input that produces "Errors" (whatever that is).

Comment: "it runs sometimes normally and sometimes makes errors" Please provide a MRE ( [mre] ) with one input each to provoke both cases. Even better, provide two separate MREs, one with hardcoded data (i.e. no input required) for good case examples and one wiht hardcoded data for error cases.

Comment: Your chances for help will increase when you spend the effort of doing SO best practices, because they will either help you directly or will improve other users willlingness to help. a) do not hide pointers b) do not ignore scanf return values c) apply consistent indentation d) init all variables (if you are sure that they will be written to beofre being read the please still init them with very recognisable values e) translate everything to English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior  due to using an invalid size in the allocation of memory in statements

```
arbre=malloc(sizeof arbre);
```

and

```
p=malloc(sizeof arbre);
```

There are allocated memory for pointers instead of objects of the structure type.

You need to write

```
arbre=malloc(sizeof *arbre);

p=malloc(sizeof *arbre);
```

Comment: If this is thes solution then it is a perfect example of why not to hide pointers. :-)

Comment: @Yunnosch yes it's the right answer, i won't typedef pointers anymore